# Script# Wrapper for Prototypal Inheritance jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, script#

I would like to create a Script# wrapper for existing jQuery plugin. The jQuery plugin implements the "Prototypal Inheritance With The DOM-To-Object Bridge Pattern" that can be found on [this link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/)

```
// myObject - an object representing a concept that you want 
// to model (e.g. a car)
var myObject = {
  init: function( options, elem ) {
    // Mix in the passed-in options with the default options
    this.options = $.extend( {}, this.options, options );

    // Save the element reference, both as a jQuery
    // reference and a normal reference
    this.elem  = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);

    // Build the DOM's initial structure
    this._build();

    // return this so that we can chain and use the bridge with less code.
    return this;
  },
  options: {
    name: "No name"
  },
  _build: function(){
    //this.$elem.html('<h1>'+this.options.name+'</h1>');
  },
  myMethod: function( msg ){
    // You have direct access to the associated and cached
    // jQuery element
    // this.$elem.append('<p>'+msg+'</p>');
  }
};


// Object.create support test, and fallback for browsers without it
if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}


// Create a plugin based on a defined object
$.plugin = function( name, object ) {
  $.fn[name] = function( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if ( ! $.data( this, name ) ) {
        $.data( this, name, Object.create(object).init( 
        options, this ) );
      }
    });
  };
};

// Usage:
// With myObject, we could now essentially do this:
// $.plugin('myobj', myObject);
// and at this point we could do the following
// $('#elem').myobj({name: "John"});
// var inst = $('#elem').data('myobj');
// inst.myMethod('I am a method');
```

Comment: What's the question again?

Answer (score 1):

Building import libraries for jQuery plugins is illustrated in the code present in the script# github repository.

In particular:

- jQuery and jQuery UI import library: https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/src/Libraries/jQuery ... your pattern looks a bit similar to jQuery UI widgets.
- Samples for various jQuery plugins such as Lightbox, and Isotope: https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/samples/Photos

Hopefully those can serve as a guide to get started...